# How to apply AND condition inside the RewriteRule (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to apply AND condition inside the RewriteRule? For example, I want to redirect to mypage.php file and pass an argument only when user not typed any of the "data1" and "data2" and "data3" as a parameter. Other than "data1" and "data2" and "data3" argument value, system should call mypage.php by passing the given argument.

```
RewriteRule ^/?mypage/((?!data1)&(?!data2)&(?!data3)).*$ mypage.php?arg=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^/?mypage/((?!(data1|data2|data3)\b).*)$ mypage.php?arg=$1 [L,NC]
```

You need to use a Pipe **|** to negate multiple  sub strings in an URI.

((?!data1|data2|data3).*) means any chars zero or more times excluding **data1** , **data2** and **data3** .

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine if I typed any data that don't have prefix of data1,data2&data3. If any data that have prefix of data1 or data2 or data3 then it is not working. For example: if data is "xyz" or "abc" is working but If data is have "data1xyz" or "data2abc" is not working. Do we have any solution for this?. Anyway thank you very much for your solution that solved my primary issue.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^/?mypage/((?!(data1|data2|data3)\b).*)$ mypage.php?arg=$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Thank Anubhava. It is working perfectly. I was struggled more than 6 to 7 hours to get the right Regex pattern, now I got what I want.